# java junit test cases not consistent

Tags: java, math, junit, primitive, testcase

I'm new here, hi all. I looked around already for some info on this and didn't find anything, but I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing. I've got a simple program that I'm trying to test which uses linked list numbers to perform arithmetic. My test cases generate random int values and checks the answer using primitive addition, subtraction, multiplication. The problem I'm seeing now is that when I run the tests repeatedly, the primitive operations are returning incorrect results, but my linked-list number arithmetic is correct. Is is possible that there are variables in memory that do not get cleaned-up between repeat junit test case runs? Sometimes it works correctly and sometimes it doesn't.

BTW I'm using Eclipse and JUnit 4. Here's my test code. Thanks for any help!

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.Random;

import org.junit.Test;

public class NumberTest {

@Test
public void testRandomIntAddition1() {
    Random generator = new Random();
    int i = generator.nextInt();
    int j = generator.nextInt();
    Number a = new Number(""+i);
    Number b = new Number(""+j);
    Number sum = a.add(b);
    System.out.printf("The first number is %d\n", i);
    System.out.printf("The second number is %d\n", j);
    System.out.printf("The primative sum is %d\n", i + j);
    System.out.printf("The Number sum is %s\n\n", sum.toString());
    assertEquals(sum.toString(),""+ (i+j));
}

@Test
public void testRandomIntSubtraction1() {
    Random generator = new Random();
    int i = generator.nextInt();
    int j = generator.nextInt();
    int k = i - j;
    Number a = new Number(""+i);
    Number b = new Number(""+j);
    Number diff = a.subtract(b);
    System.out.printf("The first number is %d\n", i);
    System.out.printf("The second number is %d\n", j);
    System.out.printf("The primative diff is %d\n", k);
    System.out.printf("The Number diff is %s\n\n", diff.toString());
    assertEquals(diff.toString(),"" + k);
}
}
```

Here's sample output that shows an incorrect result for primitive subtraction:

```
The first number is -504267212
The second number is 454054464
The primitive sum is -50212748
The Number sum is -50212748

The first number is 1820929887
The second number is -1488686395
The primitive diff is -985351014
The Number diff is 3309616282
```

Comment: Doesn't this point to a problem in your Number class ?

Comment: I would *not* use randomly generated numbers in your tests, btw. It makes tracking down issues *very* difficult. e.g. your could have a combination of numbers that trigger an overflow condition, and then not be able to repeat that in a subsequent run in the debugger

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for commenting. I don't think so. The failure in the sample output is with the subtraction operation performed by basic java, i - j. As I calculate it, 1820929887 - (-1488686395) = 3309616282. This is the result my Number class came up with. I can't understand how the java arithmetic for 1820929887 - (-1488686395) = -985351014 happened. The result seems completely out of left field. Don't you think so? Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, overflow. That could be the problem. I suppose I should put a limit on the range of the random number to keep that from happening. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Brian, you helped me out a lot! I've used a long to calculate the primitive sum and differences, and it's definitely made a huge difference in the number of junit failures. I'm still getting an odd failure once out of every 10 tests or so...

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that your numbers are overflowing, you might want to look at JUnit's `Parameterized` class to run tests like this. That way you can generate a list of pairs of random numbers and use them for both your addition and subtraction tests. It also allows you to change the number of tests easily and have separate failures instead of single one.

```java
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class NumberTest {
    static int trials = 100;
    static int MAX_VALUE = 1 << 30; // To prevent overflow

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> randomVals() {   
        Random rnd = new Random();              
        List<Object[]> stuff = new LinkedList<>();
        for( int a = 0; a < trials; a++ ) {
            stuff.add(new Object[] {rnd.nextInt(MAX_VALUE), rnd.nextInt(MAX_VALUE)});
        }
        return stuff;
    }

    int i, j;

    public Number(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i; this.j = j;     
    }

    // Your tests here, using i and j above.

}
```